# Can "daisy chain" be a verb?

Tags: verbs

I edited [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/9160/can-i-daisy-chain-multiple-displays-with-thunderbolt) and used "daisy chain" as a verb. I'm wondering if that title is technically grammatically correct.

Comment: Ah - you're from CHAOS!  Now I understand the Ψ!

Comment: Yup! In the flesh. I'm not a custodian of ELU, though - that's my excellent colleague [Lauren Ψ](http://english.stackexchange.com/users/11387/lauren).

Comment: Many nouns have been verbed.

Comment: @mgkrebbs Would that cause a chain reaction?

Comment: @mgkrebbs Adjectival nouns verbify adverbially.

Comment: @mgkrebbs http://www.gocomics.com/calvinandhobbes/2013/01/28

Comment: Stop daisy chaining these comments!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[To daisy-chain](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/daisy-chain) (preferably with hyphen) means to cascade—output of item 1 feeds into item 2, output of that feeds into item 3, etc.  Compound verbs are permitted in English, so yes you can use this one.

Comment: About 1/3 of all the written references in NGrams *don't* have a hyphen, so your implication that only the hyphenated form is correct seems unnecessarily prescriptive.

Comment: haha - you retain the prescriptive edge, I see! :)

Comment: I'm not really a prescriptivist, but in this case (as with multi-word adjectives) I find it much easier to parse with the hyphen.  And you did say that 2/3 of the NGrams you looked at used it, so it's pretty common.

Comment: I'm not really criticising - I think historically with these kind of 'neologisms' where a compound noun starts getting used as a verb, they usually start life with a hyphen, then become fused into a single word. There's a sort of continuum of *rare / not uncommon / usual / normal /standard / correct* involved, and it's often hard to know where to place any given usage on that scale. Particularly since many usages are in the process of moving along that scale in one direction or the other, and dictionaries can't always keep up.

Comment: Did your ngrams take into account noun versus verb?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you [can daisy chain](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=can%20daisy%20chain&year_start=1980&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) as a verb (this chart is about 1000 written instances).
[image: .]

Obviously OP doesn't need a definition, but in case anyone else does...

Originally a [daisy chain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daisy_chain) was simply a garland of plucked daisies, linked together by splitting the stem end of each and threading the next stem through (children often make them from daisies growing in the lawn between mowings).

By metaphorical usage the term has been extended to many "chained" processes or configurations. Particularly, as in OP's case, to the linking of multiple electronic/computer components, each with a "pass-through" socket so the next device can be plugged in to the same shared control wiring.

Metaphorical usages are often (but not always) hyphenated, particularly when using as a verb.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds good to me.

I've probably used "daisy chain" as a verb 100 times for every time I've used it as a noun.

Comment: Makes me wonder why it's not in dictionaries as a verb, then.

Comment: @drm65 Here, I've found [a link](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/daisy-chain) for it. (Sorry I edited out the part you responded to, but now I forgot what I said.)

Comment: @Kit: You could be right, but even so, [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/daisy+chain) should at least link somewhere for the verb form.

Answer (score 3):

Perfectly valid. "To chain" has been a verb, simply meaning to link in a series, for quite some time, so it's only natural that the related term "daisy-chain" (evoking an image of large "nodes" - flowers - tied together) would follow.